# Is there any difference between "visit someone" or "come to visit someone"?

Tags: phrases

Is there any difference between *visit someone* or *come to visit someone*? For example:

> My old friend **visited** me yesterday.
>
> My old friend **came to visit** me yesterday.

I have heard English native speakers say both. If both have the exactly same meaning then why would a native English speaker say the second sentence when it is longer?

Comment: We don't always say things in the shortest way possible! _Came to visit_ is said from the perspective of being at home and your friend coming to where you were. If you had visited him, you might say "I went to visit X yesterday."

Comment: Obviously yes, since you can **go to visit** someone. “Came to visit” is a subset of “visited”.